# Upgrade step to remove profile

Tags: plone, upgrade, genericsetup

We have one package that we identify that we don't need its profile ([`collective.js.cycle2`](https://github.com/collective/collective.js.cycle2)) so I need to write an upgrade step to remove the existent profile.

Looking at the code I usually have to update profile, I found that in the end it calls: [`portal_setup.runAllImportStepsFromProfile(profile, purge_old=False`)](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.upgrade/blob/master/plone/app/upgrade/utils.py%23L134)

Is it a good practice to run `portal_setup.runAllImportStepsFromProfile(profile, purge_old=True)` to remove the profile? ( I didn't find anything at `plone.app.upgrade.utils.py` to make it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add to the product an **uninstall profile** (and commonly is a good idea to add it to the original product, through a pull request).
An uninstall profile must remove all the persistent changes done by the install ones, so look at it: https://github.com/collective/collective.js.cycle2/tree/master/src/collective/js/cycle2/profiles/default

The only "dangerous" thing you must really care about is the `browserlayer.xml`. The registered CSS is not dangerous, but removing all is a good idea.

See also  [How to make your Plone add-on products uninstall cleanly](http://blog.keul.it/2013/05/how-to-make-your-plone-add-on-products.html)

After that: commonly an uninstall profile is run when you uninstall the product, but you can keep it "installed" and manually run the uninstall profile from the `portal_setup` ZMI tool.
The weird side effect doing this: you uninstalled but the add-on is still in the "installed add-on" list.